# jQuery to prevent user from inputting if regular expression is not matched by using preventdefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, preventdefault

Every time user enter, value is checked with regular expression, I'm trying to restrict user from entering further into input field if regexp is not matched

Using keyup event, preventdefault never fires and using keypress event, user is unable to input at all because in the begining, value in input field shows as "" (nothing)

[image: on keyup val="2"]

[image: on keypress val="1"]

```
var discountRegex = /(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/
            $("#" + (idOfElement)).on("keyup",function (e) {

                var val=this.value
                var k = e.keyCode
                if(k==46 ||(k > 48 && k <97)){
                    console.log(k)
                    return discountRegex.test(val);
                }

            });
```

in the above code idOfElement is the id i get on whichever field i focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the regex is matched and if not you can remove the last char like the example below

I updated the code with keydown example

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/pensive-taussig-trtop?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: is there no way to cancel the event like we can do for keyPress?

Comment: I updated the code. You get get char from keycode with the function 
String.fromCharCode
and than return the result of regex

Comment: the above code accepts special character also, please help me the code

Comment: you can use keypress and remove if with key evaluation. Why have you added this statement?

Comment: Because it doesn't work out in either way, i tried with keypress and keyup too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207200/discussion-between-ankita-gupta-and-marco-moretti).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer sample code. If input key is invalid input will not accept it. Also please find fiddle for same in comment.

```
<input type="text">


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input").bind('keypress', function(e) {
  var str = e.keyCode;
  if (/(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,2})?)$/.test(str)) {
          alert('Invalid')
       e.preventDefault();
    } else {
       alert('Valid');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Fiddle link for my answer https://jsfiddle.net/shivpatne/gpx3f6Lu

Comment: the above regex is for value less than 100 and can only accept upto 2 decimal poit

Comment: You can replace it with required regex

Comment: Do you need help with regex accepting value less than 100 and upto 2 decimal pt.?